# Text split by space and by half of text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I wanna split text by space and that space must be the middle space between text. The excel text to column function cannot use this two criteria together.

example *[] = one cell

```
[445 Mount Eden Road Mount Eden Auckland]
```

So there is 6 space between the text and I wanna split it by 6/2= 3 third space

```
expected result = [445 Mount Eden ][Road Mount Eden Auckland]
```

Comment: Use the `split`-command to get single words and then concatenate the words according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Well there is probably an simpler formula but this works:

In cell C2:

[image]

```
=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(CHAR(36),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(36),(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")))/2)))&"]"
```

And in D2:

```
="["&RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(CHAR(36),SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",CHAR(36),(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")))/2)))
```

You could obviously piece the two together into a single formula.

Comment: Why array? (`CSE`)  Seems to work fine normally entered.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, you are right, argghhh thought searching nth occurence should be entered through CSE but in fact there is no need. Thanks for noticing :)